# Stuck : filling html <ul> with <li> using Javascript with a loop?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have a function that retrieves last 10 facebook posts, when i use console.log(); it displays messages correctly.but when trying to fill a ul with each message as a list item it only displays the first message and i can't seem to fix it. thanks in advance

```
function getInfo() {
  FB.api('/me', 'GET', {fields: 'first_name,last_name,name,id,posts.limit(999),email,picture.width(150).height(150)',}, function(response) {
   document.getElementById('myname').innerHTML = response.name;
   document.getElementById('myemail').innerHTML = response.email;
   var gpost = document.getElementById('myposts').innerHTML = response.posts;
  ///////////Only last 10 status posts/////////////
   var postcount =0;
   var ul =document.createElement('ul');
   for(var i=0;i<999;i++){
     if(!gpost.data[i].message==" "){
        if (postcount<10){
          var li = document.createElement('li');
          var list=document.getElementById('myposts').innerHTML=gpost.data[i].message;
             li.appendChild('list');
            ul.appendChild(li);

         console.log(gpost.data[i].message);
         postcount++;
    }else{
      break;
    }
   }       
  }
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "<img src='" + response.picture.data.url + "'>";
  });
}
```

Comment: li.appendChild('list'); ?

Comment: `li.appendChild(list);`.. Remove `' '` around `list`..

Comment: is it really necessary to always go to 999? Isn't the array limited to gpost.data.length? I also don't know what your `list` assignment would be concidering that you chain setting the innerHtml with the message. One could wonder why you get the the `myposts` element all the time. You are also not really adding the ul to your document, so I am guessing, the only message that comes is the 10th postcount one

Comment: thanks, but it gives same results when i remove ' ' @GuruprasadRao

Comment: Could you please post sample data getting from FB?

Comment: @Icepickle thanks, but it's working if i console.log(), the 999 maybe an overkill , the message that comes out is only the (first). my bad : it's the 10th post as you mentioned

Comment: @GuruprasadRao data appears as normal text in console and only the last post appears in page here it is "Taher M. Abdelazim Ahmed Bahaa Mahmoud Hatem El Ghandoor" just tagged names.

Comment: When I try the code, it blows up at line li.appendChild(list) because list is not an object. There is one item in the list because the code errors out before it can go through the loop a second time.

Comment: You are not adding `ul` element to your dom. You are seeing only first message because its the element with id `myposts`, not the list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think during your testing you tried out some interesting variants, like getting the list from the document, and then trying to add your new list, eg:

```
var list=document.getElementById('myposts').innerHTML=gpost.data[i].message;
li.appendChild( list );
```

I am not sure what you wanted to do with this statement (you get the myposts element, set the innerHTML to your received message, and then you append the result of that action to your newly created li.

Why not set the innerHTML of the li element at once like so:

```
li.innerHTML = gpost.data[i].message;
```

Another thing you seem to be forgetting is that you don't really add the `ul` element back to your document at the end, I think, after the for loop, you are forgetting this (in case you wish to replace the content)

```
document.getElementById('myposts').innerHTML = ul.outerHTML;
```

I created a code snippet with a mock of the FB api (at least, from what I can read from your initial post) and updated your snippet so you can see what is actually happening

Main changes would be the for loop, that got a bit easier

```
for (i = 0; i < gpost.data.length && postcount < 10; i++) {
  if (gpost.data[i].message) {
    li = document.createElement('li');
    li.innerHTML = gpost.data[i].message;
    ul.appendChild(li);
    postcount++;
  }
}
```

and the fact that I replace the content of the myposts element

```js
'use strict';

var posts = [{
            message: 'message1'
          },
          {
            message: 'message2'
          },
          {
            message: null
          },
          {
            message: ''
          },
          {
            message: 'message5'
          }
        ];

// just for testing purposes
var FB = {
  api: function(item, action, fields, callback) {
    callback({
      name: 'name',
      email: 'email',
      posts: {
        data: posts
      },
      picture: {
        data: {
          url: '/favicon.ico'
        }
      }
    });
  }
};

function getInfo() {
  FB.api('/me', 'GET', {
    fields: 'first_name,last_name,name,id,posts.limit(999),email,picture.width(150).height(150)',
  }, function(response) {
    document.getElementById('myname').innerHTML = response.name;
    document.getElementById('myemail').innerHTML = response.email;
    var gpost = response.posts,
      postcount = 0,
      ul = document.createElement('ul'),
      li, i;
    for (i = 0; i < gpost.data.length && postcount < 10; i++) {
      if (gpost.data[i].message) {
        li = document.createElement('li');
        li.innerHTML = gpost.data[i].message;
        ul.appendChild(li);
        postcount++;
      }
    }

    document.getElementById('myposts').innerHTML = ul.outerHTML;
    document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = "<img src='" + response.picture.data.url + "'>";
  });
}

getInfo();

/* add some messages from time to time for the next 5 seconds */
var interval = setInterval( () => posts.push({ message: 'message' + ( posts.length + 1) }), 500 );

// stop the interval in like 5 seconds
setTimeout( () => clearInterval( interval ), 5000 );
```

```html
<div>
  <div id="myname"></div>
  <div id="myemail"></div>
  <div id="myposts"></div>
  <div id="status"></div>
</div>
<button type="button" onclick="getInfo()">Get messages</button>
```